# Incorporating license key approach for a WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, licensing

I need some guidance on where to research further incorporating license key enablement for a WinForms application.  That is incorporating those key concepts you see often such as:

- 30 day trial
- Need license key to unlock the application beyond this
- Possibly the ability to unlock power user functionality using this approach

What is the normal approach people use to achieve this?  Is it possible just using VS2008 Pro edition for example, or are there well known libraries that help out?  Would be nice to think there were "client libraries" out there that let you incorporate this relatively easily into one's Windows Forms app.

[Possible Duplicates]

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424955/prevent-casual-piracy-for-simple-utility
- [Most secure way to license software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275196/most-secure-way-to-license-software)
- [How do I best obfuscate my C# product license verification code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501988/how-do-i-best-obfuscate-my-c-product-license-verification-code)
- [How to generate and validate a software license key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599837/how-to-generate-and-validate-a-software-license-key)