# Installer Class For Validate Serial Number MS Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, installation, custom-action

I create a setup project in visual studio and want to add custom action to validate serial number. How can I do it?

**EDIT 1:**
I add `Customer Information` dialog in user interface of my setup project, and set `ShowSerialNumber` property to True. and want to validate entered user serial number , when user click next button on this dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS solution explorer

Right click **yoursetup** >> **View** >> **USerInterface**

Right Click **Start** >> **Add Dialog** >> **Select TextBox**

[image]

Now made a `Custom Class` And add `Install class` file

In Install.cs

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
                base.Install(stateSaver);
    }
```

Comment: I want to use Customer Information Dialog box and use SerialNumberTemplate. no Text Box Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want, or [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), still ...

Make a boolean function:

private static bool isValidSerialNumber( string number )
{

}

The way you validate it depends on the type of serial number scheme used,

This might involve performing an RSA decryption on the serial number, or it might be as simple as querying a database or list to see if the serial number is there.

take a look at this question: [How are serial numbers generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715251/out-of-curiosity-how-are-serial-numbers-generated-hints-algorithms)