# how generate serial number in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have table like this:

table1:

`sr no. | id | name`

id is the primary key here.
I want `sr no.` to be cyclic.
What attributes i should give to `sr no.` field?

For example I have 5 records with `sr no` 1,2,3,4,5 and `id` 1,2,3,4,5 and i delete 3rd record then `id` will be 1,2,4,5 and `sr no.` will be 1,2,3,4 
`sr no` should not lost its contentiousness.

Comment: "I want sr no. to be cyclic." What do you mean with that?

Comment: it should be like: 1,2,3,4,5,6.....
if any record gets deleted then it should update again like 1,2,3,4,5...
it should be not like 1,2,3,5,6....
if 4 no. record is deleted

Comment: so what is the difference between `id` and `sr no.`?

Comment: I don't understand for what is serial number. However, take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715251/out-of-curiosity-how-are-serial-numbers-generated-hints-algorithms

Comment: can you let us know what purpose sr no is it going to be used ?
you can think of creating trigger on delete action and UPDATE the records which having id greater than one which is deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  @a:=@a+1 serial_number, 
        name  FROM    table1,
        (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;
```

Comment: You just missed the `order by id`

Answer (score 1):

`id` is already your primary key, so what do you need `sr no.` for? Would suggest to forget about it.

If you **really** need it, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643938/mysql-delete-autoincrement/13644089#13644089) for the several reasons why this is a really bad idea. The most important reason:

> There are reasons why MySQL doesn't automatically decrease the
>   autoincrement value when you delete a row. Those reasons are
>
> - danger of broken data integrity (imagine multiple users perform deletes or inserts...doubled entries may occur or worse)
> - errors may occur when you use master slave replication or transactions
> - and so on ...

No need to worry about gaps.

To answer your question how to do it, just add `auto_increment` in the column definition and include it in the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about the real purpose of sr no.

But you can create `Trigger` on **DELETE** operation for this table, now you can update the records which are greater than current ID so that sr no is decremented by 1.

e.g. you can write below SQL in Trigger,

```
UPDATE table1 SET sr_no = sr_no -1 WHERE id > XYZ;
```