# Algorithm: create efficent look up table from integers

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, encoding, lookup

I want to create a look-up table in Python that associate integers to a series of symbols.
The symbols that I want to use are small letters [a-z] and numbers [0-9].

My goal is to represent a large amount numbers with the fewest symbols possible.
I want to know what is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

Comment: Are you effectively talking about using a base-36 number system, i.e. like hexadecimal but with a-z instead of just a-f?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181919/python-base-36-encoding

Comment: thanks to `Iftah` I found what I was looking for here
[a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715251/out-of-curiosity-how-are-serial-numbers-generated-hints-algorithms)

Answer (score 2):

If your integers are positive, contiguous, and start at or close to 0, use a list. Otherwise, use a dictionary. If your target values are *single characters*, you can use a string instead of a list.

Lists (and strings) are more efficient at mapping a sequence (0, 1, 2, etc.), dictionaries are more efficient at mapping *disparate* numbers to values.

Mapping integers to single characters:

```
targets = "a8B2Vgj4l" # targets[3] -> 'B'
```

Mapping integers to multiple characters:

```
targets = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', '42andahalf'] # targets[3] -> 'baz'
```

Mapping *noncontiguous* integers:

```
targets = {42: 'Life', 81: 'Monty Python'}  # targets[82] -> 'Monty Python'
```

Comment: thanks for your effort and explanation , but maybe I did a mistake with my question when I said 'look-up' table because what I wanted is the encoding in 36base

Comment: by the way , my numbers go from `0 to 2^40`

Comment: @user2776193: see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377); always explain what problem you are solving.

Comment: ok thanks , I will do it in future

Comment: @user2776193: note that the dupe I linked you to uses a string to do the mapping. `alphabet` is the sequence mapping integers to single characters.

Comment: I know, in fact now I am not sure to use encoding or mapping, with mapping I will use many less symbols to represent a number , but the negative side is to generate the table