# How would I go about licensing a WPF windows application

Tags: .net, wpf, licensing, software-distribution

I have developed a small application that I would like to try and sell but I am unfamiliar with how best to go about this.

1. How would I go about locking the program down for trial use1.
2. How would I go about dealing with accepting payments?

Bearing in mind that I am a one man band with not a lot of money, I was hoping for a solution that would be free or a low cost, effective, secure and simple to implement and maintain.  This is not something that I have a lot of experience with as I have typically developed for the public sector where they buy a solution as a whole and we have never licensed it.

Any help would really be appreciated.
Thanks,

B

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I can tell you how I do it. Disclaimer: your mileage may vary. This is for the case of preventing casual piracy of a simple WinForms or WPF or other desktop app. It's not particularly robust or secure against sophisticated cracking, but it does a great job of preventing casual piracy.

1. For licensing, I tried several 3rd party solutions. They're all fairly easy to use for the nominal case of *preventing casual piracy*, which of course if the only piracy you should really be concerned about.
2. What I found was that none of the licensing providers were really compatible with the existing payment processors / gateways. There are a few "all-in-one" solutions but the level of technical debt there was unacceptable to me (a freelancer and sole developer). I was looking for a simple way to go from a "Buy Now" link on a website to unlocking the desktop software after purchase. Some of the existing "all-in-one" solutions are overkill for this purpose, some ignore the "purchase" aspect entirely.
3. I ended up using [Xml Digital Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx) to sign license files with the application's private key, which is never distributed to users. The result: you have a .LIC or .LICX file on the target machine that users can read (it's plain text, except for the enveloped signature) but not modify. (Or rather, they can't modify it without you *knowing* they've modified it.) This little file is the key to the whole system.
4. When the application loads, it verifies that the XML signature is valid (using the application's public key, which *is* distributed with the app) and if it's valid, it reads the information from the license file, and enables/disables certain features based on that. For example, your license file could contain a product expiration date, or a couple pieces of unique machine info (be careful, always, not to inconvenience your legit users with this...you don't want them to have to reapply for license keys every time they change out a hard drive).
5. As an additional (and slightly more invasive) step, you can have the app connect to your server, though this gets you into server downtime issues and so forth and so on. Some devs are willing to put up with this, others aren't.
6. Now for the purchase part, there are many many options. Paypal is far and away the easiest. You may or may not like their rate plans, but it's an absolute cinch to get up and running with Paypal.
7. For that you want a Premier or Business account, not a Personal account. Note: in the Paypal docs it sometimes says you need a Paypal Business account. Whenever they say that, they actually mean, "a Paypal Business or Premier account".
8. Now get yourself a product website and customize your Buy Now buttons etc. When the user makes a purchase, your website will receive a ping from [Paypal IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn), which is their notification service. This ping is just a call to a defined HTTP endpoint on your website, and it contains all the information you'll want about the purchase. Mainly, the user's email...
9. (Okay, I feel like I should mention: Paypal along with most other legit processors have a "sandbox" where you can test all this out before going live. Does wonders towards giving you the warm fuzzy about actually going live, with money on the line.)
10. Which you'll use to auto-send the user an Activation Code after purchase, so they don't have to wait 24 hours for you to manually send them a code. Store this activation code (which under this scenario can be any unique, difficult-to-guess number, such as a GUID, prettified or not) in the DB with a usage count which you'll track to detect duplicate codes.
11. The user enters the Activation Code into the software, via a screen you provide.
12. The software contacts the server over https (this is a one-time thing that happens only when the software is unlocked), and says, "hey, is this license code the user just gave me valid?"
13. If the supplied activation code matches the code stored in the database at the time of sale, and that activation code hasn't yet been confirmed, then Success!
14. The server then needs to build the license file, which is an extremely simple XML or text file containing "what this copy of the software is allowed to do". There's no standard for what it should contain, only a few conventions.
15. The server **signs the license file with the application's private key** and returns it as a data stream to your application...
16. Which saves it as a .LIC or .LICX (or whatever extension you want) file, which it then checks on load time as per Step 3.

This has worked really well for me, and it's a cinch to implement. The key to the whole thing is simply: trust those XML DSigs. When the LIC file is missing, you default to trial mode. When the sig is modified, you switch to trial mode. Only when the LIC file is present, validly signed, and contains the right information, do you then (in code) open up access to "full" functionality.

Also, interperse more than one license-check point in your code. I do one at app startup, another at idle, and another just before entering key functional areas. So if someone does reverse the code, and they can, they'll at least have to do a bit of searching to gut all the license checks. Of course, nothing you can do can prevent people from patching their way around those checks. You just want to make it a bit more difficult.

Comment: Great walkthrough.  Behind the scenes, I'm pretty sure this is all that Desaware is doing for us, but we can do it on a component level, and we only have to write about 2 lines of code per app.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I've used Desaware and it's a sweet tool. Highly recommended if going commercial is an option.

Comment: Cracking answer, this is exactly the type of information I was looking for. Thanks for spending the time and putting it together I am sure that I am not the only one that will get use from it.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck~ may your software become popular enough to BE pirated. :)

Comment: Good answer, one question.  At step 10, why not just generate the license file and attach this in an email to the customer at this point.  The activation code seems redundant as it doesn't include something specific to the users computer which would stop running the application on multiple computers.

Comment: This is indeed a great answer, but like the comment before mine, I will also dig this answer with a question. Cant a user who just did all these steps correctly, provide the final .LIC or .LICX file to other users?

Comment: @Santux not if you gather information from the user's computer and use that info to validate the license in you check-points.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it correctly, I would honestly have to recommend buying a trusted third party solution for both of these things.  There are several licensing packages out there for .Net (we use [Desaware](http://www.desaware.com/products/licensingsystem/index.aspx) for our products, although I haven't directly worked with them that much so I couldn't give a detailed recommendation.  It seems simple enough for what I've been exposed to).  No fuss, no bugs, and the payoff in the long term is huge in terms of time saved.

Third party payment services can handle online credit card transactions for you, and there's always PayPal as well.  Google for "how to accept credit card payments on the web" and you'll come up with endless merchant solution providers.

If you'd rather spend the time to build a licensing system yourself, [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453030/how-can-i-create-a-product-key-for-my-c-app) is a pretty good resource on the various aspects to consider.

Comment: thanks womp, as I don't have a lot of money to invest in this I think I am going to have to roll my own.  Have you any experience using any of the payment gateways?  The sheer number of them is a bit overwhelming, it would be great to get feedback from someone who has experience and would be able to advise of the pro's and cons.

Comment: I don't have any personal experience.  A colleague uses 2co.com, aka 2checkout.com.  He says they charge 5-6% plus a transaction fee.  I don't get the impression that he recommends them very highly ;)

Comment: I would disagree with just one thing: for simple sales of a simple app where time-to-market is critical and best-of-breed protection isn't crucial, I think rolling your own is a viable approach. On the other hand, if 400,000 users depend on your software running smoothly...heh. Not something I'd try to do myself in a million years. +1 though.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use some form of [Software Projection and Licensing](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Security/Products_and_Tools/Software_Protection_and_License_Control/) for .NET applications.  There are hundreds of options out there, from very inexpensive (and articles for how to roll your own) to very robust commercial tools.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Reed. I know there are hundreds of options and it can be confusing at best.  I was hoping to get some guidance on what would best suit a small software vendor that is bootstrapping.

Comment: @Burt: I'd be happy to offer suggestions -but we need a lot more info.  What's your budget?  What are your requirements? etc...

Comment: @ReedCopsey, I am looking for a product key/serial key generator to tie into InstallShield LE (or full version) for Visual Studio 2012.My company would like to purchase a third-party generator. What are some suggestions? Budget would be around $1000 max or so. The generator would have to tie into InstallShield. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider [CryptoLicensing For .Net](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm) - it provides options for full as well as trial (usage days, unique usage days, executions, etc). It also comes with ready-to-use license server with e-commerce integrators for paypal, shareit, plimus, etc.

Comment: very extensive software - might want to consider reading a getting started guide first: http://www.mashitup.be/how-to-use-cryptolicensing/