# How do I make a serial/key system?

Tags: drm

I would like to make a serial/key system for my program so the user has to enter their serial/key to get the program updated. How would I do so? I am horrible with databases. :\
Thanks alot! :D

Comment: Do you really need to "make" your licensing system, or would you be willing to purchase instead?

Comment: Well, I'm on a $3 budget. If there's anything below my budget, then I will buy it, if not then I will just attempt to make one.

Comment: You could always pirate a licensing system :)

(For anyone who missed it,that was a joke based on the irony of pirating an anti-piracy prevention tool and NOT an actual suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889842/tips-for-securing-application-with-a-licence-key-system), and other questions linked from there such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453030/how-can-i-create-a-product-key-for-my-c-app). Most are asked by people using other languages, but answers deal with abstract concepts that apply to any language. Note that this is not an easy problem to solve anyway, and a solution can only be "good enough", never perfect.