# How can I secure my C# software with a registration key during setup?

Tags: c#, registration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a Product Key for my C# App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453030/how-can-i-create-a-product-key-for-my-c-app)

I am developing some software with C#.
I want the software to run on a specific system with a registration key.
I want to generate a key for it. How can I make a setup program for it?
Please help me to develop the setup for it with system registration.

Comment: exact duplicate of [How can I create a Product Key for my C# App](http://stackoverflow.com/q/453030/11343)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend purchasing and using a [3rd party licensing system](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20licensing%20system) instead of rolling your own.

I personally have had good luck with the [Eziriz products](http://www.eziriz.com/), which provide a lot of functionality for the price.