# Time based serial key generation for PC Software

Tags: c#, desktop-application, windows

How can i generate serial key for the C# Desktop Application (Windows application) ?

E.g. Software expires after a month. (Trial version).

If user changes Machine time then hoe could it be possible to validate the software for the specified time ?

Comment: This stackoverflow post can probably help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453030/how-can-i-create-a-product-key-for-my-c-sharp-app

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can generate serial keys for your application in C#. You will most likely have make some sort of trade off between the simplicity (ie. the length of the key, readability, etc), and the security of a particular system.

I would recommend Software Protector(http://softwareprotector.clizware.net/) and SKGL (https://skgl.codeplex.com/). Software Protector would give you a user interface where you can generate your keys and SKGL API would allow you to validate those inside your own application. If you like, you can also include the source code of SKGL API (currently available in C# and VB.NET). You can set a time limit from 0 to 999, 8 custom features, and machine locking.

Regarding the time changing issue, the only way I see is to look up the local time (for that time zone) online using **time.windows.com** and check if that is equal to the current time on the pc. Please check this article: https://skgl.codeplex.com/discussions/472444

*Please note that I am developing both SKGL API and Software Protector, which means that my answer might have a slight tendency!*

Comment: Hello, @Artem, SKGL is not available for .NET Core, and your website isn't currently active. Where can I get your source code? Or is there another alternative?

Comment: Hey @BibekShah! Cryptolens is the successor of SKGL: https://help.cryptolens.io/faq/what-is-skgl